# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: func.apply is not a function at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to redirect to another page when my component function is called. but It is giving me an error.
Here my code is

```
        <SuggestedSolution
            budgetData={budgetData}
            onClickgetSolution={(val) => {
              console.log('CLICK ', val);
              return history.push('/abc');
            }} />
```

Here my console log is showing properly but when I tried to redirect It is giving me this error.

[image]

Comment: Which element is calling the `onClickgetSolution` function. please share more code around `SuggestedSolution` components

Comment: on that component as of now, just a simple button for click my concern is redirecting code. My log is showing properly so I guess on SuggestedSolution component doesn't have an issue.

Comment: redirecting code is just `history.push('/abc")` . assuming that `history` is what we are expecting it is, i don't see any issue here. Something else is causing the issue. is your console.log working in `onClickgetSolution`?

Comment: yes, consol.log is working

Comment: Try removing the `return` statement. Modify it as `history.push('/abc')`

Comment: @need_to_know_now same error

Comment: what 's `history` here?

Comment: `import { useHistory } from 'react-router';`

`const history = useHistory();`